# Search for specific text at the start of the URL in Google search

Tags: google-search

How do I search for websites that start with “dl” on Google?

For example, returned sites search will be like

```
dl.webaddr.com
dl.something.com
dl.others.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Netcraft.com may give you better results with its Search Web by Domain feature.

A wildcard search for `dl.*.*` with [this query](http://searchdns.netcraft.com/?restriction=site+contains&host=dl.%2a.%2a&lookup=wait..&position=limited) returned results showing more than 500 sites having dl as the subdomain.